# Auto-generating destinations of split files in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am working on my first SSIS package. I have a view with data that looks something like:

```
Loc   Data
1     asd
1     qwe
2     zxc
3     jkl
```

And I need all of the rows to go to different files based on the Loc value. So all of the data rows where Loc = 1 should end up in the file named Loc1.txt, and the same for each other Loc.

It seems like this can be accomplished with a conditional split to flat file, but that would require a destination for each Location. I have a lot of Locations, and they all will be handled the same way other than being split in to different files.

Is there a built in way to do this without creating a bunch of destination components? Or can I at least use the script component to act as a way?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set an expression using a variable. Define your path up to the directory and then set the variable equal to that column.

You'll need an Execute SQL task to return a Single Row result set, and loop that in a container for every row in your original result set.

I don't have access at the moment to post screenshots, but [this link should help outline the steps.](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11113/ssis-dynamically-set-flat-file-connection-manager.aspx)

So when your package runs the expression will look like:

```
'C:\Documents\MyPath\location' + @User::LocationColumn + '.txt'
```

It should end up feeding your directory with files according to location.

Set the `User::LocationColumn` equal to the Location Column in your result set. Write your result set to group by Location, so all your records write to a single file per Location.

Comment: Thanks. While trying to accomplish this method, I stumbled upon a video that had an alternative method. I got it done now. Would +1 if I could.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time try to complete this task using the method @Phoenix suggest, but stumbled upon [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCoRM2Zc09E) along the way.

I ended up going with the method shown in the video. I was hoping I wouldn't have to separate it in to multiple select statements for each location and an extra one to grab the distinct locations, but I thought the SSIS implementation in the video was much cleaner than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Change the connection manager's connection string, in which you have to use variable which should be changed.

By varying the variable, destination file also changes
and connection string is :

'C:\Documents\ABC\Files\' + @User::data + '.txt'

---

vote this if it helps you